# What is the Greisen-Zatsepin-Kuzmin (GZK) cutoff and why does it happen?

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmic-rays

I was just wondering, what is the  [GZK cutoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit) point and why does it happen? Some say it is some sort of 'lattice' in the universe; https://www.google.ie/amp/s/io9.gizmodo.com/5950543/physicists-say-there-may-be-a-way-to-prove-that-we-live-in-a-computer-simulation/amp

Is this true?

Comment: Have you looked on Wikipedia for the [GZK cutoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit)? It's pretty well described there

Answer (score 9):

A sufficiently high-energy photon-proton interaction produces a short-lived Delta baryon, which decays into a pion and either a proton or neutron. Thus a proton has only a $50\%$ chance of "surviving" such an interaction, and can only do so a fairly small number of times; with at most $10^{87}$ protons in the observable universe, and enough CMB photons in between cosmic-ray sources and Earth to allow for far more than $87\log_2 10$ such interactions, the only protons we expect to see in cosmic rays are those that no longer have enough energy to form the Delta resonance.

Solving $(p_p+p_\gamma)^2=(p_n+p_\pi)^2=(m_n+m_\pi)^2$ (working with $c=1$), $p_p\cdot p_\gamma=\frac{(m_n+m_\pi)^2-m_p^2}{2}$. An ultrarelativistic approximation lets us rewrite this dot product as $2E_pE_\gamma$, so $E_p\approx\frac{(m_n+m_\pi)^2-m_p^2}{4E_\gamma}$. See Eqs. (7)-(16) [here](http://www.hep.shef.ac.uk/edaw/PHY206/Site/2012_course_files/phy206rlec5.pdf).