# Do high speed particles see light as a different part of the EM spectrum due to the Doppler effect?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, doppler-effect

If a particle was travelling fast enough and had visible light shot at it, would the partice experience the light as if it was higher or lower wavelength? If so, would the particle see the incident light as having different energy? This doesn't seem right, as its the same light whether the particle is moving or not, so it should have the same energy.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this happens in space all the time. Ultra-high energy cosmic rays, e.g. protons, collide with cosmic microwave background photons of about $\epsilon \sim 10^{-3}-10^{-4}$eV, see them as fantastically *blue shifted*, and photoproduce pions and are thus absorbed.
This is the celebrated [GZK effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit).

As a result, protons with energies of over  $\frac{m_\pi (2m_p+m_\pi)}{4\epsilon} \sim 5\cdot 10^{19}$ eVs, ~ 8 J,   do not survive over long distances (~160 million light-years), degrading their energy to pions,
$$\gamma_{\rm CMB}+p\rightarrow\Delta^+\rightarrow p + \pi^0, \\
\gamma_{\rm CMB}+p\rightarrow\Delta^+\rightarrow n + \pi^+. $$

You may think of cosmic photons stopping protons as water stopping deep penetration of bullets.

Energy varies with your frame, so in the center of  momentum frame, where you see the proton and the photon collide head on, you experience the colliding photon blue-shifted to a  γ-ray  monster with energy close to a pion's mass---can you figure it out?

(Hint: look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/405323/66086) outstanding answer,  $E_\gamma\geq\frac{m_\Delta^2-m_p^2}{2m_\Delta}$.)

- *Edit  explaining the pion production threshold commented upon.* In the lab (universe, CMB) frame, consider the proton momentum *p* needed for a proton-pion system at rest in the c.m. frame. So, in the lab, the proton photon system has energy-momentum $(\sqrt{m_p^2+p^2}+\epsilon, p-\epsilon, 0,0)$, whose square is a relativistic invariant, so it must match the c.m. frame's. That is, 
  $$
  (\sqrt{m_p^2+p^2}+\epsilon)^2-(p-\epsilon)^2=(m_p+m_\pi)^2 \Longrightarrow \\
  4\epsilon p =m_\pi(m_\pi + 2m_p), 
  $$
  where I have dropped a  truly negligible $m_p/p$ term, in view of the answer (dominant balance). This is the formula provided above.

Comment: So, is it correct to say that only protons with energies over 5⋅1019 eVs produce pions, because that is the energy equivalent to the mass of a pion from e=mc^2?

Comment: Effectively.... I write above a more detailed and complex formula arrived at from the equation of the invariant square of the energy-momentum 4-vectors. You want more detail on its derivation?

Comment: What is the meaning of the four variables to describe energy-momentum of a system? (I don't yet have a university physics eduction)

Comment: [Relativistic 4-momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum).

Answer (score 0):

This principle is used to measure the electron/position beam polarization at HERA (DESY). HERA is a storage ring, so that synchrotron radiation polarizes the lepton-beam via the Sokolov-Ternov effect. This causes a transverse polarization to build up in the storage ring which can then be rotated to longitudinal polarization in the interaction region.

Compton scattering

$$ \gamma e^{\pm} \rightarrow \gamma e^{\pm}  $$

with circularly polarized photons is used to measure both the transverse and longitudinal polarization. Of course, Compton scattering is traditional X-ray or gamma-ray scattering off of atomic electrons; however, in this case it is YAG or CO2 laser photon (i.e., light per the OP's question) striking a 28 GeV electron or positron beam.

Here an frequency doubled YAG photon with a 532 nm wavelength is seen by the beam as an X-ray:

$$ E'_{\gamma} = \frac{1.23\,{\rm eV}}{\lambda/\mu m}\cdot \frac{28{\rm GeV}}{m_e=0.511\,{\rm Mev}} \approx 130\,{\rm keV}  $$

In the lab frame, the backscatter photon is a gamma ray that is detected in calorimeters. Spatial and/or energy asymmetry is proportional to beam polarization.